# What is the preferred way of handling imageio in Java?

Tags: java, javax.imageio

I am working on a code base which was developed 2 years ago. The code used jai-imageio (as a dependency from dcm4che). Apart from running into many problems(64bit win OS etc), I discovered that there are many different ways of handling imageio in Java now. A few of them being:

- https://github.com/jai-imageio/jai-imageio-core (old but still used in many projects)
- https://github.com/geosolutions-it/imageio-ext/ (jai-imageio page recommends it)
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html (included in Java)

I would primarily be dealing with DICOM images and JPEG2000 format, but since I am in process of upgrading the code-base, which of these(or other) is the most preferred/recommended way of performing imageio with Java ?

Comment: I don't get the question - or rather the way it is asked. There is only ONE ImageIO - the one in the JDK. But there are also many extensions to that one ImageIO adding support for all different kinds of filetypes and such - that is JAI and that third party imageio-ext you link to. That last one is the most confusing as the page you link to states literally "Additional plugins and extension for the standard Java ImageIO library ".

Comment: I found dcm4che using jai-imageio which is not developed now. And also found that Java also has a standard imaging library. Since jai doesn't support 64bit windows and likewise standard imageio doesn't have support for JPEG2000, the question is aimed towards what would be better way to perform imaging operations including advanced operations such as zoom etc.

Comment: "the question is aimed towards what would be better way to perform imaging operations including advanced operations such as zoom etc." I suggest you just ask this as a new question, as this is not what the current question is about (from my understanding). :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is pretty subjective and will likely be closed as such, but in my opinion, unless there's a compelling reason for you not to use the standard Java library, give it a go and see how you get on. At the very least it will reduce the dependencies that your project has, which is always a plus.

Comment: dcm4che is dependent upon jai-imageio that's why I need to use it. Just don't know if it can be replaced as is by using standard Java functions.